# assigning a function variable to another function

Tags: javascript

First up - n00b with Javascript here and I did try to search for something which represented similar concept as the one I have below but I couldn't find anything useful..sorry if my search skills are rather limited.

I'm going through the Eloquent Javascript and under the "Nested Scopes" section, there was some code showing how the scope of functions works; the following is the code (And a bit that I've added to experiment)

```
var landscape = function() {
    var result = ""; 
    var flat = function(size) { 
        for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
            result += "_";
    };

    var mountain = function(size) {
        result += "/";
        for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
            result += "'";
        result += "\\";
    };


    // my nonsensical code -- begin

    var myfunc = function(text) {
        console.log("this is only a block of text -", text);
    };

    // my non sensical code -- end


    flat(3);
    mountain(4);
    flat(6);
    mountain(1);
    flat(1);

    // this is what I was trying to do and see what happens here..
    mountain = myfunc("meh");
    // end of my nonsense

    return result;  
};
console.log(landscape());
```

I understand that if within my function (`myfunc`) if I assign a value to `result` then when `result` is returned in the last line, it will get overwritten with whatever value is being assigned to it in `myfunc`

My question here I guess is what does it really mean to be able to assign one function variable to another (`mountain = myfunc`) and is there a real world usage to such a "feature"? If not, why does Javascript allow such an assignment?

Comment: You are not assigning a function to mountain. Your code is calling the function and since your function does not return anything, it will store undefined into mountain.

Comment: Since you're not assigning a function variable to another, your question doesn't really make sense. Maybe you copied the code incorrectly from the book.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
mountain = myfunc("meh");
```

Assigns the return value of `myfunc` to `mountain`.

Since `myfunc` only logs something, it returns `undefined` (which is the default return value when no explicit return value is given).

Therefore, at the end of the example you've given `mountain` is `undefined`.

This is very useful, however, when you have functions that return other values. For example:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function multiply(c, d) {
  return c * d;
}

function divide(e, f) {
  return e/f;
}

var multipliedThing = multiply(add(1,2), add(3,4));
var anotherMultipliedThing = multiply(add(5,6), add(7,8))

var result = divide(multiplied, anotherMultipliedThing);
// => 0.12727272727272726
```

The above is a bit contrived, but it shows a use case for assigning the return values of functions to variables.

The core concept of functions is general is to accept some value and return a value. With JavaScript (and many other  languages) you get the "benefit" (I put that in quotes because it's debatable in some circumstances) of functions giving side effects (that is, mutating other values outside of the function). Therefore, if a function's purpose is for side effects, you might not need to return anything.

Look up "functional programming" if you're interested in a little bit of theory.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
mountain = myfunc("meh");
```

you are calling `myfunc` with `"meh"` as parameter and assign its return value to `mountain`. The `function` logs a text and finishes. Since it does not have a `return` statement, it returns `undefined` and as a result, `mountain` will hold `undefined` at the end of the day. If, instead of that, you are doing this:

```
mountain = myfunc;
```

then the function named `myfunc` will be assigned to `mountain`, so, if you call `mountain` after this operation, it will execute `myfunc`.

> My question here I guess is what does it really mean to be able to
>   assign one function variable to another (mountain = myfunc) and is
>   there a real world usage to such a "feature"? If not, why does
>   Javascript allow such an assignment?

The meaning of that is that you are able to store functions inside variables. It is a very useful feature, which you are using yourself when you define `landscape`, `myfunc` and `mountain` initially. Basically, a `function` can have properties, so there is literally an arsenal of possibilities you can do with a variable holding a `function`.